# Passing a Windows Service Parameters for it to act on

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, service

I want to turn a program I have into a service so I can use it without logging it. Basically what it does is it backs up specified folders to a specified location using SSH. However the problem I'm running into is I don't know how to tell it these items. I only know how to start, stop, and run a custom command with only an integer with a parameter.

How can I do this?

**Windows Service, not a Web Service**

**edit**: The folders it backs up will not remain consistent and will be updated at every runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any service is capable of receiving command line arguments at start-up.

Comment: When you start the service you can specify them, but only if the service is manually started. For automatic the arguments have to be in the registry (as others pointed out) or in a configuration file.

Comment: Can I start a service without the user logging in first? I.E. remotely?

Comment: What about the OnStart(String[] args)?

Comment: You can control (start and stop) a service remotely (if you're priviledged and have network access): by using an API, by using an O/S GUI, and/or by using the "net start" command from the command line.

Comment: You can also change entries in the remote registry, e.g. if the service is reading its startup parameters from the registry.

Answer (score 6):

You can instantiate your service and pass command line arguments using the ServiceController class.

```
using (ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(serviceName))
{
   string[] args = new string[1];
   args[0] = "arg1";
   serviceController.Start(args);
}
```

"arg1" will then be available as regular command line arguments in main() when Windows starts up the service.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you (or someone) voted Sebastian Sedlak's answer down, because he mentioned hosting a WCF Service in the Windows Service. Your reply was

`It's in nice bold lettering in the question. Not a Web Service, therefor WCF is out of the question`

I think you misunderstood what he meant. He wasn't talking about a **Web Service**. He was talking about hosting a **WCF Service** *within* your **Windows Service**.

It's far from the same thing. You can host a WCF Service *within* any Windows (Forms/Console/Service) application. The point of doing so, is that the *application* is then reachable for communciation via its internal WCF Service, in the same *fashion* as you can communicate with a Web Service (you can *also* host WCF Services in IIS, btw, which would *then* make them "Web Services", in the sense you seem to be referring to).

In a Windows Service, this means you can send any command to it and also get any information you want from it - while it's running.

In fact, I am working on a project right now, which is a Windows Service that I need to be able to contact and pass commands to - and get information from - at runtime. For example, I want to be able to tell it where to store certain things, what to log, to have it reset/restart - and poll it for status messages. I do this by hosting a WCF Service inside the Windows Service. That WCF Service exposes a set of methods, that in my case includes receiving commands and returning status information. So when the **Windows Service** is running, I can contact it (even remotely), via its built-in **WCF Service** and tell it what to do.

This an extremely easy thing to implement, and in the case of Windows Services, can provide you with a much richer interface to the Service than through the basic standard commands.

**However**, you specified that you wanted your Windows Service to receive its folder settoings each time it *starts up*, which makes such a passive setup less than ideal (as it would be unable to do anything until you passed it the right folders).

One way to deal with this (using a hosted WCF Service), would be to have the Windows Service running *all the time* (i.e. automatic startup). Its default state would be idle. Then you could issue it a "start processing"-command, feeding it the correct folders to work on (through a call to the corresponding WCF Service method). Similarly, the WCF Service would expose methods giving you the status of the application (current folder, progress, busy/idle etc). Once the processing is done, it would go back into the idle state, waiting for the next set of folders to be supplied to it.

Doing it this way would make it very easy to control remotely - you could even make an online administration panel for it, accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The issue, is that, while passing in parameters is not difficult, when the machine restarts and windows tries to restart the service, those parameters are not there. they only exist when someone starts the service from the command line.

for example. I have a windows service which hosts a WCF service. I want the users to be able to specify a non-default port number for the WCF service to listen on. They do this by starting the windows service like so...  MyService -port:xxxxx

Which works fine, until the server is rebooted, then windows restarts MyService (but without parameters) and the wcf service defaults to original port #

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to use a configuration file to specify these items?

Comment: I don't think so. Considering the user won't be logged in, and will have to specify the folders each time because they may/will change.

Comment: I see.  That would rule out registry entries as well.  I agree with ocdecio and Dave though, off the top of my head you should be able to send a string as an argument to a service.

Answer (score 1):

Store the service's startup parameters in the registry: and then, when the registry starts, it should read its startup parameters from the registry.

Comment: Folders change per use. Sorry, I forgot to state that.

Answer (score 1):

Windows services have executables like any other.  I believe you can write it to accept command-line parameters and specify those parameters in the Windows Service configuration.  You can also have it read a config file.  If you're using .NET, there are config file classes in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just Host a WCF Service in the Windows Service to obatain such "admin" functions?
(Remoting is also possible)

Comment: See my answer for a comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

RE: config file.

Of course a config file can be used.
And the file can be changed while the service is running.

This would be a nice solution if the config file changes in fact.
All my services use an XML config file, wrapped in a class for easy reuse.

The wrapper has an option to monitor the XML file using fileMonitor for changes, optionally refreshing the content of the config file automatically, and finally raises an event to the service class.
The service then has the option of "resetting" itself as needed to incorporate the new values in the XML configuration file.

Placing configuration into the registry has a few issues:

- Security (ie: installer being granted access), depending on what tree is used
- The service will not be aware of changes
- Portability - although minor as the install should setup registry settings

Where an XML file is easy to copy, edit, share, view and understand.
Throw in some good COMMENT blocks and a detailed XSD file, and it becomes a source of good documentation too.

Look into XPath for easy navigation and extraction of values within the XML file.

$0.02
... david ...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the app.config file - I'm rather sure that your service will read and use those files as I write all my windows-services this way ;)
So just put everything you need in the app.config under "application" (not user) and put allway edit the "yourname.exe.config" in the folder where you "InstallUtil" the service from.